# Splash screen determining, which Activity to load on startup?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-handler, splash-screen, android-thread

I am making a Splash screen, which determines which `Activity` to load, based on whether the App is being started for the first time *(or not)*..

The code is running in it's own Activity - `MainActivity`, which will act as the Splash screen. If it's the **first time starting**, I load `IntroActivity`.. If it's been **started before**, I load `PrimaryActivity`.

I have a couple of **Questions**:

**1)** - Is using `runOnUiThread` the correct way to do this?

**2)** - I have researched topics relating to Splash screens here on StackOverflow, which suggest the use of a `Handler` - is this recommended in my *specific* use case?

**3)** - Should I be closing this `Thread` once I determine which Activity to load, and if so, how should I go about doing this?

*Bonus:*

**4)** - I intend to eventually make this Activity be a pop-up style loading window..

**What is the simplest way to achieve this?**

Thanks in advance for any help provided!

---

My current code is shown below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //  Make a Toast pop-up.
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Checking Settings...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    ////  BEGIN PREFERENCES CHECK  ////

    //  Set the wait time for the Splash screen.
    final int SPLASH_WAIT_TIME = 5000;

    //  Start new Thread to check for first start and load appropriate Activity.
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

                //  Wait before continuing.
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(SPLASH_WAIT_TIME);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            //  Initialize SharedPreferences.
            SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

            //  Create a new boolean and preference and set it to true.
            boolean isFirstStart = getPrefs.getBoolean("firstStart", true);

            //  If the App has NEVER started before...
            if (isFirstStart) {

                //  Declare an Intent for loading IntroActivity.
                final Intent intentLoadIntro = new Intent(MainActivity.this, IntroActivity.class);

                //  Launch IntroActivity.
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override public void run() {
                        startActivity(intentLoadIntro);
                    }
                });

                //  Make a new Preferences Editor.
                SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = getPrefs.edit();
                //  Edit Preference to make firstStart False so Intro never loads again.
                prefsEditor.putBoolean("firstStart", false);
                //  Apply the changes.
                prefsEditor.apply();

                //  Close MainActivity so the Back hardware button doesn't return to it.
                finish();

            }

            //  If the App HAS been started before...
            else {

                //  Declare an Intent for loading PrimaryActivity.
                final Intent intentLoadPrimary = new Intent (MainActivity.this, PrimaryActivity.class);

                //  Launch PrimaryActivity.
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override public void run() {
                        startActivity(intentLoadPrimary);
                    }
                });

                //  Close MainActivity so the Back hardware button doesn't return to it.
                finish();

            }

        }
    });

    //  Start Thread t to determine Activity to load after Splash (MainActivity).
    t.start();

//  END of onCreate.
}

//  End of MainActivity.
}
```

Comment: Do you realize waiting 5+(!!!!) seconds just for the first screen to show up is horrible user experience? Also, it takes time for this Activity to show up so the sequence is like: `User clicks on the app from the home screen, they see a white or empty screen, then your MainActivity pops up for 5 seconds and then another delay to load PrimaryActivity `.

Comment: Read here more why your approach is horrible https://android.jlelse.eu/the-complete-android-splash-screen-guide-c7db82bce565 and here how to properly do it https://android.jlelse.eu/right-way-to-create-splash-screen-on-android-e7f1709ba154

Comment: @ZUNJAE I only use 5 seconds for testing purposes.. Also, the App seems to open and show the MainActivity immediately, and then wait, prior to loading the appropriate activity, as intended.. But I will certainly look into the Links you provided. Making this a better flow is exactly why I created the Topic. Thank you for your contribution. If anybody else has anything to add, I would be most grateful. Thanks again.

Comment: That's on your device. Now try on an older one :)

Comment: This is simply how Android works. During a cold start, some devices will either see a blank screen or they're stuck on their app launcher. It's just that your phone is fast enough (and you app is minimal, so not much resource loading). This becomes a big problem once your app grows and people with worse hardware than your phone start using your app.

Comment: starting for the first time is pretty simple and there shouldnt be any type of wait at all. if (sharedpref.getbool(firsttime, false){//user first time, go activity a} else { //go activity b} if the user is there for the first time, you send them to what activity, and in there you would update the shared pref. you shouldnt implement any type of waiting. I have a half second wait in my splash screen not for this, but for "loading" effect. so, i wait .5 seconds, then run that if statement. pretty straight forward. you are over thinking it.

Comment: @ZUNJAE It was actually tested on the Emulator believe it or not. I'm about to check out your links right now, and I will let you know if I have any questions.. My only initial concern is that I'm not simply showing a Splash screen - I'm also determining which Activity is appropriate to load after. But thank you for taking the time to help, and I will post again shortly after I go thru your links!

Comment: As your application becomes bigger, the amount of resources bundled with it start to affect the startup time. Anyways, a splash screen delay during which you are not doing anything is generally something any user would _hate_ if they knew it wasn't loading anything during the wait. If the application is worth it, later you would like to add some image decoding, network code etc to start up during it already.

I would run the finish() from the UI thread as well, just to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best way to do it. Get the shared pref to see if its the users first time. If it is, take them to the first time activity, other wise, take them to main activity.

If the user deleted the app and reinstalled, they are considered first time users again since this information is stored on the local device. If you want this user based, implement a database to store these tags by the user id. However, the flow would be similar.

In your onCreate of your Splash activity

```
//  Initialize SharedPreferences.
SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

//  Create a new boolean and preference and set it to true.
boolean isFirstStart = getPrefs.getBoolean("firstStart", true);    

Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if (isFirstTime) { //first time user is here.
            Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, FirstTime.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } else { //user has been here before.
            Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }
}, 500);   //half second
```

In your first FirstTime activity, once the user is done doing whatever you want them to do, you then will update your shared pref and move them BACK to the splash screen to verify.

```
//  Make a new Preferences Editor.
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = getPrefs.edit();
//  Edit Preference to make firstStart False so Intro never loads again.
prefsEditor.putBoolean("firstStart", false);
//  Apply the changes.
prefsEditor.apply();
// Go back to Splash...
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstTime.this, Splash.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: Handlers threads etc. are discouraged by Google and a lot of other people. Look at the comment I posted on the original question.

Comment: Discouraged by Google? Please provide a Google doc explaining, and not some blogger who has an opinion. I have access to plenty of devices with older SDKs, all is fine with this approach.

Comment: Google changes their opinion about threads and background runners yearly.
Using the handler or a thread are both just fine. An asynctask would be fine too, but really, it's way overkill for doing a simple timed action like this and will end up doing just the same anyways.

Asynstask, handlers etc are supposed to just make the code easier to manage. If it quadruples the amount of lines it's not achieving that. Just because there is some wrapper functions in Android doesn't mean that you're supposed to use them for everything - and that's what they are: wrappers.

Comment: @LassiKinnunen i agree. I only have a handler for the purpose of having the splashscreen display. Otherwise it may never get there/show.

Comment: There's a nice video here made by Google about this topic https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E5Xu2iNHRkk . It starts around 1:50

Comment: There are more talks about Google first disliking launch screens then suddenly implementing it their self. Their issue was that branding was done incorrectly and too much against user experience

Comment: @ZUNJAE i agree with all of this. However, how is the developer handling it? If you have a screen displaying with no progress, just there, this gives the presents of a page stuck, or froze. OR, throw a logo, progress bar, then throw the user into the mainactivity. you can do plenty of reading in between the lines here. They state that its not good to load up tons of services in the load screen, this isnt done. and actually, my app goes into a "activity" that extends Application, then Splash, then Main (or first time). This takes no more than .75 seconds. IF THAT.

Comment: If google didnt like they, they would send Handler to the curb like they have many other packages.

Comment: Why do you need a progressbar for something that only takes 0.75 seconds? I can link you to more articles about Google being against your approach. Want to start a chat?

Comment: it gives a better effect than just an image. we can argue all the time. the matter that google doesnt agree with a handler is false. the matter than there are better ways around it, sure, maybe, depending.

Comment: And they sure aren't going to send the Handler to the curb due to depending on it. The whole UI/Event loop depends on it. https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui .  At some point someone at Google decided it would be a good idea to write wrappers around the wrapper that it already is and there you have the miscommunication about them being bad. 

fwiw I modded this back up. I don't see why it was at -1.

Comment: Thank you all for your input! The desired effect was achieved using the answer from DroiDev, with slight adjustment. The Handler post delay method of doing this is much more efficient than running it using a Thread that sleeps, as I was previously doing. Thanks again y'all.